# JavaScript Objects and Element ids

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The goal of my project is to create a matching picture game, where the user clicks on two images. After each 
time an image is clicked, it will be flipped to its alternate image. If two pictures match, then I will remove 
(or hide) the two images. The game completes when all the pictures are removed.

I have a snippet of HTML, which looks like the following.

```
<body>
    <img src = "somepicture.jpg" onclick = "SomeFunction()" id = "pic0">
    <img src = "someotherpicture.jpg" onclick = "SomeFunction()"  id = "pic1">
    ...etc...
</body>
```

I also have JavaScript code, which generates each  elements and gives each element attributes.

Each time I generate an img I want to link it with a piece object, which I declared myself. The idea of the 
piece object is to be able to store a member variable state, which determines if the picture is facedown (not clicked)
or face-up (selected).  But I am unsure how to link the id attribute of each img element with the piece object
that I have created. Or if this is even the best way to solve this problem....

I was thinking about making an array of Pieces. The index of the array should match with the last character of the img element's
id attribute.

For instance, piece[10] will map to document.getElementById("pic10"). But I am not sure how to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance for your inputs!

Comment: No its not. I swear :D I already graduated from college. I am just learning HTML/JavaScript. It's an assignment that I came up with for myself My goal is to eventually make Tetris, which I have done before using Java. But I wanted to start with something simliar first.

Comment: Javascript in college? Nah, that's just C and Java. Javascript you end up learning on your own when you enter the real world and realize you don't know any current tech even though you just graduated.

Comment: Very true PherricOxide. that's the boat that I'm in right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of an `onclick` attribute, attach a "click" event handler to your images. Event handlers receive an [event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event) as the first attribute.  The event object's `target` attribute contains a reference to the dom element that raised the event. So you can get the id of the image that raised the event with `event.target.id`.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays can contain text keys. Use that.

```
var pieces = [];
pieces['pic10'] = "active";
```

Comment: i think this is misleading... you're adding a property called `pic10` to the object `pieces`, which just happens to be an `array`, but it is not an element of the array. http://jsfiddle.net/jbabey/yyTF8/

Comment: It's a simple associative array and it will likely serve the purpose of the post.

Comment: an associative array in javascript is an object, not an array - that's why this is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

For a really simple but not terribly elegant solution, you could just build the id string up from a prefix and the index of the array.

For mapping index i in the array,

```
document.getElementById("pic" + i)
```